# Django how to turn a python string into a javascript string and render it to the website

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I'm working with Django and in my views I'm sending my page a string of HTML:

```
 <p><code>202</code> </p><p>hello world/p>
<ul>
<li>Goodbye<strong><em>next</em></strong> or <strong><em>happy</em></strong> to go on.</li>
</ul> byebye <p>&lt;3</p>
```

However, it gets sent to the page as:

```
    var html_smallest_steps =     
     &lt;p&gt;&lt;code&gt;202&lt;/code&gt; &lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;hello world/p&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;Goodbye&lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;next&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; or &lt;strong&gt;&lt;em&gt;happy&lt;/em&gt;&lt;/strong&gt; to go on.&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;
```

and I get a console error on my page:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'`

My views.py is:

```
def displayDict(request):
    html_ss = 
""" 
    <p><code>202</code> </p><p>hello world/p>
    <ul> <li>Goodbye<strong><em>next</em></strong> or <strong><em>happy</em></strong> to go on. 
    </li> </ul> byebye <p>&lt;3</p>
    """
    return render(request, 'chatStream.html',
    {"html_sss": html_ss})
```

And chatStream.html is:

```
<p id="chatLine">get this working!!</p>

    <script>
    var html_smallest_steps = {{html_smallest_steps}}
    } 

setTimeout(myTimeout2, 2000) 

function myTimeout2() {
  document.getElementById("chatLine").innerHTML = "html_ss  " + html_ss;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.utils.safestring import marksafe

def displayDict(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'chatStream.html',
    {"html_sss": mark_safe(html_ss)})
```

Or you can use `safe` tag in your template.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe

Comment: isn't the use of `safe` considered a bad practice since it makes the code vulnerable to XSS attacks?

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Kaminiski... I was able to import marksafe... for some reason now instead of the issue with '&', I'm getting an issue with: ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'```, where ```var html_ss =     
     <p><code>202</code> </p><p>hello world</p>
<ul>
<li>Goodbye<strong><em>next</em></strong> or <strong><em>happy</em></strong> to go on.</li>
</ul> byebye <p>&lt;3</p>``` seems to be hanging the page up

Comment: OK so what worked was using mark_safe() and also adding \".....\" quotes at the beginning and end of the string. The browser is rendering the string as code inside the javascript